# How can I set up unit tests to run for different environments?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm considering running unit tests for my Visual Studio 2010 projects on our build server at build time.  The problem is that when I'm working locally, I want to test against DEV, when building for QA, I want the tests to run against QA, when building/promoting for UAT/PROD...  you get the picture.

I think VS 2010 might have support for per-environment configs.  If so, does this apply for test projects also?  If not, what are some alternatives?

thanks,
Mark

Comment: Sounds like your tests are integration/system tests rather than classic unit tests. Are DEV, QA etc. different databases, or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have much experience with VS 2010, but there was no such functionality in VS 2008.

I usually have a msbuild script to build and run the tests of the solution. In your case I would have a step in the this script to set the correct configuration after the code was built and before the tests are run. I used XmlUpdate task from http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ last time.